# How to re-validate a form after it has been re-loaded

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

The first time I validate a form it works fine. When the form is valid I save the form instance for future use.

```
MY_GLOBALS[form_instance] = $('#form-section').clone(true);
```

When I re-load this form, and I empty a required field, the form is not validated. 
Before saving the form instance I even removed the valid classes;

```
$("#form-section").replaceWith(MY_GLOBALS[form_instance]); // load saved instance
```

So validation only works when I start with a new #form_section instance.
I also tried to force the validation. But it returnd true all the time, when the form was reloaded.

```
console.log('check', $('#myform').validate().form() );
```

By the way: the actual form: #myform is part of the #form-section. The html looks like this :

```
<section id="form-section">
    <form id="myform" action="/" method="get" novalidate="novalidate">
```

novalidate has been added by the plugin. Removing it before the save, has no effect.

Comment: `$("#form-section").replaceWith(MY_GLOBALS[for*n*_instance]);` Is that just a typo in your example?

Comment: Yes : $("#form-section").replaceWith(MY_GLOBALS[form_instance]);

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#myForm')` when u reload the form

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it did not solve my problem. And the error markers disappeared.